# a required argument is missing: /key:[Sonarqube project key]

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run sonarqube analysis but I am getting the error

```
"a required argument is missing: /key:[Sonarqube project key]"
C:\Sonarqube\sonarqube-6.7\sonarqube-6.7\bin\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /key: {projectkey} /name:{projectname} /version:{1.0}
```

[I have used the following url](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Scanning+on+Windows)

I have tried using the "" in Key and Name but still get the same error

can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: There's a space between `/key:` and `{projectkey}`, is that a typo or could this be the problem?

Comment: Ohh Thanks Fabrice. That was the problem.

Comment: OK,  great, so I will put it as answer to have this question "answered" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in the command line: the space between `/key:` and `{projectkey}`. This is what produces this error message.

Comment: `projectkey` stands for? Is it the unique-id that points to the solution in .sln file?